# How to catch changes in building docker image?

Tags: docker, deployment, dockerfile

I am new to docker container. I met a problem about how to catch changes of my code. Some lines in my local style.css file have been changed. Then I built docker image again, but actually nothing changed when I browsed my app.

Here are some methods I found online and tried, but didn't work.

1. remove image and build again
2. --no-cache=true
3. add a comment in Dockerfile to make it different
4. docker system prune
5. --pull

(I also used git pull to get code on my cloud instance, these files were checked to be the latest.)

I know little about docker mechanism, could anyone tell me what the problem is?

Extra info I found: 
After stopping container and removing image, I restart my instance, then build image, run container again. Only in this way, can I catch those changes. Does anyone know the problem?

Many thanks!

Comment: Did you replace the running container?

Comment: Yes. I find I can catch those changes only when I stop running container, container prune, remove image, and stop my instance, then start my instance again, build again, run container. Can you figure out what the exact problem is by this info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There appears to be a disconnect on the difference between a container and an image. The container is the running instance of your application. It is based on an image that you have already built. That image has a tag for easier referencing, but the real reference to the image is a sha256 hash and building a new image will change the hash that the tag points to without impacting any of your running containers.

Therefore, the workflow to update your running application in docker is to:

1. Build a new image
2. Stop the running container
3. Start a new container pointing to that image
4. Cleanup any old images or stopped containers

If you are using docker-compose, it automates the middle two steps with a `docker-compose up` command, and that even deletes the old container. Most users keep a few copies of older images to allow easy rollback.

Comment: I followed your steps, but when I built a new image, I saw docker was using cache, and it turned out to be the exactly the same as that container I stopped before. Then I tried to add --no-cache in building, still nothing changed.

Comment: BTW, I don't use docker-compose. I add a Dockerfile in my folder, then docker build , docker run. That's all. I also tried different tags for images, didn't work either. Overall there must be something which decides what to use in building image in docker I don't know, not just the folder I cd to.  Only by rebooting the whole instance, it seems to clean up something docker saved, then I can catch those changes I maded. Do you have any idea about what it is? (OS: Linux 14.04, docker version: 17.06.2-cd)

Comment: If the image was fully cached, then your css file is unchanged from the last build or is not included in your image with a `COPY` or `ADD` command.

Comment: Finally I found what was wrong. I checked image id, every time I changed something, a new id was assigned. If I didn't change anything, this id would be the same as previous one. And I exec to container, and found those changed I made which means the container was changed, but the page in my browser looks unchanged. I realized the problem might be the browser cache! After I cleaned up browser cache, I found my changes. Thanks for your replies, it's always nice to learn more about docker.